# AngularJS - Change Sprite Animation after it has finished

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, sprite

I am making a sprite animation for my landing page. I have two sprite animations. First animation will start and play once and the other animation will be a infinite loop after the first animation finishes.

I know that you will toggle classes to switch the sprite animations, but how can I make Angular listen for the last keyframe of the first sprite animation?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('animation-toggle', function($scope) {
  $scope.class_status = 0;

  
  //toggle class with boolean
  $scope.toggleSingleClass = function() {
    $scope.class_status = !$scope.class_status;
    };
  
  //remove class
  $scope.removeSingleClass = function() {
    $scope.class_status =0;
    };
  //add class
  $scope.addSingleClass = function() {
    $scope.class_status = 1;
    };
});
```

```css
/* FIRST ANIMATION */
.land-animation {
    width: 700px;
    height: 493px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    background: url('../images/font-animation.jpg') left center;
    animation: play 4.0s steps(48);
}

@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: -33600px; }
}

/* SECOND ANIMATION */
.land-animation2 {
    width: 700px;
    height: 493px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    background: url('../images/font-animation2.jpg') left center;
    animation: play 4.0s steps(48) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: -33600px; }
}
```

```html
<!-- RUNNING ANGULAR 1.3.15 -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>


<!-- DIV ANIMATION -->
<div ng-controller="animation-toggle" ng-class="{'land-animation2': class_status }" class="hero-unit land-animation"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try a pure jQuery way, just include the jquery.min.js and the following code outside the controller,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hero-unit.land-animation").one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){ 
       $(this).removeClass("land-animation").addClass("land-animation2");
   });
});
```

UPDATE

to avoid the white frame in between, change your code as following,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hero-unit.land-animation").one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){ 
       $(this).addClass("land-animation2");
   });
});
```

and in CSS,

```
/* FIRST ANIMATION */
.land-animation {
    width: 700px;
    height: 493px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    background: url('http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg') left center;
    animation: play 4.0s steps(48);
}

@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: -33600px; }
}

/* SECOND ANIMATION */
.land-animation2 {
    background: url('http://cdn.phys.org/newman/gfx/news/hires/2013/spitzerandal.jpg') left center;
    animation: play2 4.0s steps(48) infinite;
}

@keyframes play2 {
    100% { background-position: -33600px; }
}
```

Comment: oh ok, I was told that adding jQuery would not mix well with angular. Is that the case? If not then I will go ahead and add jQuery to my project.

Comment: Nope...jquery wont affect the project as long as you use it for the above cases.

Comment: ok, is there a way that you might be able to help to just use angular?

Comment: You can use the ngAnimate callback feature of angularJS

Comment: I just ended up going with your Jquery answer, it works great. BUT, I have one last question. On the last frame it goes to white for like a single frame, then plays the next animation. How can I get rid of that white frame?